# SSRS Charts & Datasets

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I need help on what I believe to be a simple SSRS report function, but alas I cannot seem to get to work. I am running a SQL Server 2012, using VS2010.

The report that I'm tasked with requires multiple charts (pie, line and stacked) all based off this one query.

I have created a report with a single dataset as follows:

```
Use WWTP
SELECT DateAndTime, TagIndex, Val As Value
FROM FloatTable
WHERE DateAndTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

I then place a chart object on the report and apply a filter of `TagIndex = 1` and I drag *Value* onto the chart for the X axis and I drag `*DateAndTime*` onto the chart for the Y axis. This returns the data as required.

However I'd like to add another value onto this chart (eg. TagIndex = 2). I have tried the following:

1. Modified the Chart Filter to TagIndex = 1 OR 2
2. Removed chart Filter and applied the following expression onto the value:      `=IIf(Fields!TagIndex.Value = 1, Fields!Value.Value, Nothing)`

Both scenarios don't return anything. Should I create multiple data sets to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `BETWEEN` as the `Operator` and supplying values 1 and 2. This should work. But if you decide to include `TagIndex = 4` later, then this will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the response Amit. I have thought of the BETWEEN operator but as you have noticed that this does limit me for other scenarios. At this stage I am forced to use multiple datasets that I find is extremely slow.

Comment: You can try using something like this with the `IN` operator - `=Split("6,7,9", ",")`. For this you'll have to pass `TagIndex` as a `varchar` field. This filter should be at `CategoryGroups` level.

Comment: Hi Amit, the "IN" operator was the answer I was looking for. Thank you.